# How to create a list of possible inputs by a user?

Tags: list, for-loop

Hi guys I want to make a decision tree in python where it will accept yes or no inputs how ever a list of possible inputs such as y n YES NO yes no yep nope ect
I would really appreciate you guys to also explain the code as a I need to add notes as it is my gcse controlled assessment. Thank you guys I really hope you can help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Put your responses in `set`s.  Then you can use the `in` operator to test whether an input is contained.  But as it stands, this is not a great question.  It sounds like you're just asking people to write code for you.

Comment: no not really as i just some1 to explain the code. Thats all. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
yesArray = ['yes', 'yep', 'yeah', 'y']
noArray = ['no', 'nope', 'nah', 'n']

userInput = input('Chose yes or no')
userInput = userInput.lower()
if userInput in yesArray:
    ...
else:
    ...
```